# Saving pdf documents to a remote apache server

Tags: java, apache, scala, pdfbox

I am attempting to save a PDDocument (pdfbox) to a remote apache server.  What is the easiest way to accomplish:

```
document.save("x.xxx.xx.xx/pdfs/myNewPDFDocument.pdf")
document.close()
```

As of right now the save functionality produces an error.  I am unsure of whether this is because of limitations in pdfbox's save method, or what a possible workaround might be.

Any suggestions or tips would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like a file path to me. Try opening a command line and copy any file to that "path" of yours to see what I mean. Or read the error that you get from save().

Comment: Why do you have scala and java as labels? And what is the role of the Apache Server in the question?

Comment: My file path is the ip_address/path/to/my/file.pdf.  I am accessing a remote server at hostname@ip_address then the path to the file.   Apache server isn't important so much as accessing a server is.  The error I get from save is just "Cannot find the selected directory".  It seems to not even recognize it.  In general, is this kind of functionality possible? If so, it could be true that I'm mistaking the file path.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the type of server mattered.  I am working in scala, so used that as a tag.  All I want to do is save a pdf to my remote server.  The server is on ip address x.xxx.xx.xx and I want to save it there.

Comment: UNC paths are //host/directory or \\host\directory depending on your OS. Maybe talk to the admin of that server to arrange directory access to you.